# EXT3 file system pre digest material

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, reference

I am looking for understanding EXT3 filesystem source code. I think I need a little pre-digestion to fully understand the code. Can anyone please suggest some material(blog etc.) where I can get some basic understanding of the source code.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) and some of its references, for an overview of how it works, before diving into the source.

Comment: quick google search returned these links:

http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=421 and
http://www.funtoo.org/en/articles/linux/ffg/4/

Comment: somewhere I read that ext3 is now going to be driven by the ext4 driver...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any online resources that are going to be as helpful as this book: [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005658). Chapter 12 covers the Linux VFS layer, and Chapter 18 covers ext2/ext3 specifically.

The book probably about due for a *fourth* edition, since it's circa 2.6.10, but the basics are still the same. There's a lot going on in filesystems these days, though, so it'd be nice if the book covered ext4 and btrfs as well.